# How to retrieve appointments in UWP from a Windows 10 calendar using C#

Tags: c#, list, calendar, win-universal-app, appointment

I'm creating a Universal Windows Application in windows 10 using C# which manages appointments in the Windows Calendar App. I am able to add appointments, and can edit or delete them using the ID. However, without retrieving them and filtering, I won't know their ID.

Has anybody had any experience with retrieving a list of calendar appointments in Windows 10 using C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve all the calendar appointments using the Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentStore class.

In this example I am going to retrieve the appointments in the next 24 hours

```
AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);

var dateToShow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);
var duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);

var appCalendars = await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync(dateToShow, duration);
foreach (var calendar in appCalendars)
{
[...]
}
```

Remember to grant access to Apointments Capabilities in the package.appxmanifest

Comment: Great answer! It works! But for some reason, with me, on my next 4 events, it only loads the 3rd one :/ (Even though they're all in range). Has anyone else experienced this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/managing-appointments):

> Through the Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments namespace, you can create and manage appointments in a user's calendar app.