# C# UWP AppointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync not working on PC

Tags: c#, list, calendar, uwp, appointment

I have a UWP program which essentially retrieves a list of appointments and then filters them to produce a report.

I'm using the AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync and AppointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync as per [How to retrieve appointments in UWP from a Windows 10 calendar using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160774/how-to-retrieve-appointments-in-uwp-from-a-windows-10-calendar-using-c-sharp)

The problem I have encountered is that it works fine on the Windows 10 Mobile device, but not on the Windows 10 PC. They both sync to the same calendars.

My code:

```
AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);

            DayOfWeek weekStart = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            DateTimeOffset startingDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            while (startingDate.DayOfWeek != weekStart)
                startingDate = startingDate.AddDays(-1);

            DateTimeOffset currentPayStart = startingDate.AddDays(-14);

            var date = currentPayStart;
            var timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
            var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0, timeZoneOffset);

            TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);

            FindAppointmentsOptions options = new FindAppointmentsOptions();
            options.MaxCount = 100;
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Subject);
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Location);
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.AllDay);
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.StartTime);
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Duration);
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Details);
            options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.DetailsKind);

            IReadOnlyList<Appointment> appointments = await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync(startTime, duration, options);
```

I have older WPF code which still works fine on the PC. (but it was never implemented on the mobile)

The code:

```
var outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            var calFolder = outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;

            DayOfWeek weekStart = DayOfWeek.Monday;
            DateTime startingDate = DateTime.Today;

            while (startingDate.DayOfWeek != weekStart)
                startingDate = startingDate.AddDays(-1);

            DateTime previousWeekStart = startingDate.AddDays(-7);
            DateTime previousWeekEnd = startingDate.AddDays(0);

            Outlook.Items rangeAppts = GetAppointmentsInRange(calFolder, previousWeekStart, previousWeekEnd);
```

It seems that the IReadOnlyList is always empty when deployed to the PC, whereas my existing Outlook.Items (WPF code) works fine.

As above, the code works fine on the mobile, which was why I essentially wanted to upgrade to UWP, but now not on the desktop.

I feel I'm missing something very basic...

Comment: are you using outlook or the calendar app on your pc?

Comment: The PC uses outlook, the mobile uses standard calendar app. Both sync to the same outlook exchange account.  My UWP app works on both, it's just on the PC it doesn't read any appointments into the IReadOnlyList<Appointment> list. I've checked this by doing a var ct = new MessageDialog(appointments.Count.ToString()); await ct.ShowAsync();

Comment: The AppointmentStore isnt an api that communicates with exchange, but with the data on the system. I don't think outlook uses this api's to put the data from exchange in the system like the calendar app does. So two solutions: configure the calendar app to get the data on your pc or use exchange api's to get the data

Comment: I knew it would be a basic novice mistake! I have opened the calendar app on the PC and created the exchange account in question, and now it all works. It also explains why the phone app deployment can only see the two weeks previous, which is the app restriction, not an account provider restriction.  [link]https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-are-my-email-messages-or-events-9b6f053c-5a4d-4a2b-bae4-57cdaddd5cb7?#events

Answer (score 0):

The AppointmentStore isnt an api that communicates with exchange, but with the data on the system. I don't think outlook uses this api's to put the data from exchange in the system like the calendar app does. So two solutions: configure the calendar app to get the data on your pc or use exchange api's to get the data

Comment: It would certainly help if you explained _how_ to configure the calendar app to get the data. The suggestion is useless without one.