# C# retrieving Windows 10 Calendar with events scheduled

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, console-application, .net-4.5

I am exhausted by searching this simple thing I am looking for to retrieve Windows Calendar events for the specified date. If in System Calendar today is holiday then I want to get that information. So my question is simple how can I read System Calendar for events and check for holidays. Is it possible? How?

Comment: You mean from the windows 10 calendar app?

Comment: @Alex No, In console app

Comment: Do you want samples for System Calendar or Outlook Calendar ?

Comment: @Ramankingdom System which is mentioned

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160774/how-to-retrieve-appointments-in-uwp-from-a-windows-10-calendar-using-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160774/how-to-retrieve-appointments-in-uwp-from-a-windows-10-calendar-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Pio Not even close.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I will try to answer it for anyone struggling with the same problem:

If you are only interested in the information about holidays, you could use the [Nager.Date](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date) library as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366429/4871566) (not reading from the system calendar):

```
// Required namespace: using Nager.Date;

DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
string strCountryIdentifier = "US";

if (DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(date, strCountryIdentifier)) 
{
    // Do something here
}
```

This seems to be the easiest way to determine holidays.

Otherwise you could create an additional calender for a new user that contains only holiday events. Then it would be possible to check for holidays using the [AppointmentManager.GetForUser(User)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.getforuser) method in your application.

```
Assemblies: Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.dll, Windows.dll
Namespace: Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments
```

This assembly could also be used if you want to read the holiday information from your current user's calendar, but it would require the registered holiday events to have a unique property that could be checked to determine whether it is a holiday or just a regular meeting.